# getting error Media Player(-38,0)

Tags: android, media-player, audio

I am getting error "MediaPlayer(12807): error (-38, 0)"
When I play the sound for the first time,it plays well..but when I stop the sound and play it again it gives the above error.
My code is

```
MediaPlayer mSoundMENU;

CONSTRUCTOR(){

     mSoundMENU = MediaPlayer.create(GameManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), R.raw.mainmenu);
}
    STARTSOUND(){

    try {
                    mSoundMENU.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                            Log.e("SOUND_MENUBG", "error = "+ what+" extra = "+extra);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    mSoundMENU.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mSoundMENU.setLooping(true);
                mSoundMENU.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                mSoundMENU.start();
    }

    STOPSOUND(){
    if(mSoundMENU != null){
        mSoundMENU.setVolume(0.0f,0.0f);
        mSoundMENU.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you play again why are you called mediplayer.prepare() again?

Comment: MediaPlayer(12807): error (-38, 0) is Media player state exception. There is some problem with your playing sequence.

Comment: where you are setting data source to media player.

Comment: mSoundMENU = MediaPlayer.create(GameManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), R.raw.mainmenu);

this is called only once in Constructor. Do we need to set it again? because am not realising my MediaPlayer variable. So I think don't need to set DataSource.